# html or handlebars encoding issue when trying to send email from Mandrill

Tags: html, handlebars.js, html-email, mandrill

I want to use mandrill as mail sending provider, and looks like it support templates with handlebars.js template syntax. And in simpliest case it works fine and send email is required, so something like that sends ok:

```
<body>
<p>{{EmailBody}}</p>
</body>
```

However, when I trying to add link on the page and populate it's address with some value, all is broken due to some encoding issue.

So, I want something like that:

```
<body>
    <a href="{{Address}}">Link</a>
</body>
```

but instead of correctly parsing this it's on saving convert code to something like:

```
<body>
    <a href="%7B%7BAddress%7D%7D">Link</a>
</body>
```

which of course not working. I also try to use single quotes instead of double one, but when saving template it's still change it to double quotes and again encode `{{}}` symbols.

So, how could I fix this problem?

Comment: found this online, maybe it will help you. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying two things:

1. Check that "Address" exists by compiling it outside of Mandrill. It possible that it may be within an array or, if referenced as a partial, may need to be declared as `{{> Address}}`
2. Make sure that Handlebars is selected as your Merge Language in Mandrill as described at the bottom of here - https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content